# nrparms: SIOCADDRT: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: packet, linux, ax.25, netrom

I am learning about the Linux amateur radio protocol stack. I'm trying to connect to a remote node using netrom. My `axports` file looks like:

```
radio   N1LKS   9600    128     4       Primary RF link
```

My `nrports` file looks like:

```
# name  callsign        alias   paclen  description
nrnod   N1LKS-1 MYNOD  128     Netrom node port
nrbbs   N1LKS-2 MYBBS  128     Netrom bbs
```

Active interfaces look like:

```
14: ax0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 128 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 10
    link/ax25 N1LKS-0 brd QST-0 permaddr LINUX-1
15: nr0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 128 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/netrom N1LKS-1 brd *
16: nr1: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 128 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/netrom N1LKS-2 brd *
17: nr2: <NOARP> mtu 236 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/netrom * brd *
18: nr3: <NOARP> mtu 236 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/netrom * brd *
```

I want to connect using netrom to a node identified by the alias `FOONOD` associated with callsign `K1ABC-3` (callsigns changed for the purpose of this question). If I just run:

```
axcall nrnod FOONOD
```

or:

```
axcall nrnod K1ABC-3
```

I get:

```
call: NET/ROM callsign or alias not found
```

...which is expected, I guess, since there are no routes yet. I tried adding a node using `nrparms` like this:`

```
nrparms -nodes K1ABC-3 + FOONOD 192 6 radio K1ABC-3
```

Which fails with:

```
nrparms: SIOCADDRT: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

What's wrong with this command and why is it failing?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the kernel code, I see four things that can make an "add node" ioctl on a netrom socket return `-EINVAL`:

1. The route has more than 8 digipeaters. Doesn't look like this is the case, and `nrparms` would refuse a too-long route before it submitted it to the kernel anyway.
2. The alias given is more than 7 characters. Again, nope, and again, `nrparms` would error before the kernel got a chance to see it.
3. The port name specified for the route somehow resolves to a network interface that doesn't exist, isn't an ax25 device, or isn't up. This doesn't *seem* like it's the case, but maybe it could be if you did something weird like edit `axports` after `kissattach` was started? The easiest way to debug this is probably to reboot and start from scratch.
4. The destination callsign of the route is a callsign that's configured on the local machine. This is conceivable, depending on your "callsigns changed to protect the innocent".

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seem to be any of these things; I'm inclined to chalk it up to, "wow, the linux ax.25 stack sure is buggy".